# Smooth movement with background mousemove script

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I found out how to make a background image move with mouse movement.
I'm trying to figure out how to smooth the movement out or make it more fluid.
The most I've figured out is that by dividing by larger and larger numbers there is less background movement, but that's as far as I've gotten.

html

```
<body id="body">

</body>
```

css

```
html {
   width: 100%;
}

body {
   background-image: url("http://sherly.mobile9.com/download/media/656/49_ybQFKMAV.png");
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-size: cover;
   height:4400px;
}
```

jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#body').css('background-position', 'calc(45% - 0px)');
   $('#body').mousemove(function(e){
     var x = -(e.pageX + this.offsetLeft) / 205;
     var y = -(e.pageY + this.offsetTop) / 100;
     $(this).css('background-position', "calc( 45% - " + x + 'px' + ")" + y + 'px');
   });    
 });
```

A good example would be [from flickr after zooming in on an image](https://www.flickr.com/photos/cubagallery/3888632330/in/photolist-jNeUXn-aFLGVK-6VCfV1-o5YxS4-7M9qR6-a7NX2m-gW8HRk-nmgbrS-pJHNZV-92L3Vd-pviVFz-bBNhzQ-djxsa5-nC4THD-f7cAKn-p54QPf-ssVzX7-9CZ27J-nZgJNB-hjtCai-pXcYFv-s1Zxax-83oLKF-hXvV1Y-89Jnw5-qgZSym-kFWFjG-85qsku-fDYnp2-8CZS1C-nnJ2T4-ecAJvn-fucFmv-7vEF9w-iNftr8-6QQ1u3-f7z3jA-omJ7Lg-h1yb4R-eMte6t-8Vbkam-6XnJcW-djxs6c-qpJcnX-rbsKBc-bp72FE-jcxxRM-gmgB8E-dEf6Z4-q1LVv7).

Or this guy's site: http://ericportfolio.com/

Comment: Do not animate background position, it [causes paint](https://csstriggers.com/background-position). Use a transform.

Comment: Do not do anything like that portfolio either. That is a nightmare in terms of performance.

Comment: I think you need an space after `")"`.  to have this: `$(this).css('background-position', "calc( 45% - " + x + 'px' + ") " + y + 'px');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should separate out the background into an element of its own.

Style the element with:

```
.background
{
    will-change: transform;
}
```

To prime the rending engine to promote it to its own compositing layer. This makes `transform` changes more cheap.

Animate `transform` via `translateX(...) translateY(...)` instead of background position.

To smooth movement you can keep track of the last several position changes and average them.

---

Example with 10 sample smoothing:

```js
const root = document.querySelector(".root");
const bg = document.querySelector(".background");

const positions = [];

root.addEventListener("mousemove", e => {
  const x = -(e.pageX + bg.offsetLeft) / 50;
  const y = -(e.pageY + bg.offsetTop) / 50;
  positions.push({ x, y });
  const averageCount = 10;
  if (positions.length > averageCount)
    positions.splice(0, 1);
    
  const current = positions.reduce((acc, e) => { acc.x += e.x; acc.y += e.y; return acc }, { x: 0, y: 0 });
  current.x /= positions.length;
  current.y /= positions.length;
  
  bg.style.transform = `translateX(${current.x}px) translateY(${current.y}px)`;
});
```

```css
.root
{
  position: relative;
}
.background
{
  will-change: transform;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.overlay
{
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="root">
   <img class="background" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/35oj3.png"/>
   <h1 class="overlay">Lorem Ipsum</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: I've got it working on my project, is there any way to prevent it from creating the white space?

Comment: @BrianPatrick: Do you mean outside of the background? If so, you can scale up the background image to such a degree that it will never lead to any gaps. The exact values depend on the amount of movement possible.